# Stream Live Android Audio to Server

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming

I'm currently trying to stream live microphone audio from an Android device to a Java program. I started off with sending the live audio between two android devices to confirm my method was correct. The audio could be heard perfectly with barely any delay on the receiving device. Next I send the same audio stream to a small Java program and I verified that the data was being sent here correctly too. Now what I want to do is encode this data and somehow play it back on the server running the Java program. I would rather play it in a web browser using HTML5 or JavaScript but I am open to alternative methods such as VLC.

Here is the code for the Android app which sends the live microphone audio

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button startButton,stopButton;

public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
    AudioRecord recorder;

private int sampleRate = 44100;   
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
    private boolean status = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
     stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);

     startButton.setOnClickListener(startListener);
     stopButton.setOnClickListener(stopListener);

     minBufSize += 2048;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS","Recorder released");
    }
};

private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
                startStreaming();           
    }
};



public void startStreaming()
{
    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);


                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");
                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");


                recorder.startRecording();


                InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5");
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];


                while (status == true)
                {
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 50005);
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
                }

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
}
}
```

And here is the code for the Java program reading in the data..

```
class Server
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);



              serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
              String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData().toString());

              System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
           }
  }
}
```

I know that I should encode the audio on the app side before sending this to the Java program but I'm not to sure how to go about encoding while using AudioRecorder. I would prefer not to use NDK as I have no experience with it and do not really have time to learn how to use it....yet :)

Comment: What did you use stream audio? I want it for one way only.

Comment: I'm interested in writing an android app that streams live microphone audio from an Android device to a Desktop application. Could you please provide a few helpful pointers to some resources that are related to the content you posted? That would be immensely helpful! Thank you! :)

Comment: How you done live audio between two android devices?

Comment: Hey @chuckliddell0, can you provide me the source code of Sending audio between sender and receiver in Android? It will be helpful, as I am stuck here.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

So I got my problem fixed. The problem was mainly on the receiving side. The receiver takes in the audio stream and pushes it out to the PC's speakers. The resulting voice is still quite laggy and broken but it works none the less. Playing around with the buffer size may improve this.

Edit : you use a thread to read the audio in order the avoid lag. Also, it is better to use a sampling size of 16 000 as it is ok for voice.

Android Code:

```
package com.example.mictest2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Send extends Activity {
private Button startButton,stopButton;

public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private int port=50005;

AudioRecord recorder;

private int sampleRate = 16000 ; // 44100 for music
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
private boolean status = true;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);

    startButton.setOnClickListener (startListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener (stopListener);

}

private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS","Recorder released");
    }

};

private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
                startStreaming();           
    }

};

public void startStreaming() {


    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                DatagramPacket packet;

                final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5");
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*10);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                recorder.startRecording();


                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                    socket.send(packet);
                    System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " +minBufSize);


                }



            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
            } 
        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
 }
 }
```

Android XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Server code:

```
package com.datagram;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 44100;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);


    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1280]; 
    // ( 1280 for 16 000Hz and 3584 for 44 100Hz (use AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat) to get the correct size)

    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

    while (status == true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);

        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());

        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());

        // A thread solve the problem of chunky audio 
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(100.0f);

        sourceDataLine.start();
        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        sourceDataLine.start();

        System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I hope this helps save someone a few hours of pain :)

Comment: This creates a constant jitter and the voices are not clear. What can be done?

Comment: have u send your voice stream from one android device to multiple android device via server that is just like group conversation.I am trying to learn it but couldn't find anything.will u help me plz??

Comment: can i contact with u??

Comment: What i have found is that 44.1KHz is too high for a sampling rate when working with streaming live microphone audio. From what I am seeing, 8000 or 16000 work better as sampling rates. This goes against the recommended 44100 sampling rate as noted in the android doc but this is what I have found from my experience. Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29 for guidance on which sampling rate is best suited for the purpose of your application.

Comment: @chuckliddell0 i am working on a same app and i used your code its working but the problem is for me is there too much echo in sound and i wont to stream calls audio can you provide me some help ? if possible can your provide your contact details ?

Comment: Hay, what are the permissions that have to Allow for Audio streaming?

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: @chuckliddell0 If the backend is going to be VLC player instead of a java program. Is it possible?

Comment: Great question and answer.  
Do you know how can I play the audio on the server when server is Android and not PC?  I mean send audio from android to android

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work. Got a couple of comments though:
1- Server code: line 49: should pass only the first argument.
2- Android layout file: the 5th and 6th lines from the bottom: "button_1" should be replaced by the proper id of the first button ("start_button").

Comment: I've been streaming mic audio packets to a speech recogition server. It works fine with the latest Google App 6.0+ , but audio is glitchy and stutters when recording using older Google App 5 versions, which are usually shipped with stock OS (or when you remove all Google App updates). Has anybody else noticed this?

Comment: @chuckliddell0 what I have to do If I have to manage both things in Android only, one app can record and second app can stream audio. Any help please?

Comment: You do not need sample rate of more than 8000 for voice

Comment: i want the reverse please help me i wanna audio transfer from pc to android

Answer (score 16):

*My 2 cents to your code to improve the efficiency. Nice try*

```
package com.datagram;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 44100;

static DataLine.Info dataLineInfo;
static SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

    /**
     * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
     * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
     * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
     * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
     */

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];

    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
    dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    sourceDataLine.open(format);
    sourceDataLine.start();

    FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    volumeControl.setValue(1.00f);

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
            receiveData.length);
    ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            receivePacket.getData());
    while (status == true) {
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
        toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
    }
    sourceDataLine.drain();
    sourceDataLine.close();
}

    public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
        try {
            sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i this really help to reduce the noise?

Comment: This won't even work in android. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app

Comment: What exactly do the variables ``ais`` and ``baiss`` do in the code? I can see that they're both initialized with the received data but in ``toSpeaker`` the raw bytes are used...

Comment: If this solution is not working with latest Android, please follow this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193645/audio-not-clear-while-streaming-between-a-java-class-and-android-activity The post is based on this approach only but author has modified few changes which works well. Thanks for both the posts authors user1729564 & kittu88

Answer (score 5):

The voice is broken because of the following line in your android code:

```
minBufSize += 2048;
```

You're just adding empty bytes. Also, use `CHANNEL_IN_MONO` instead of `CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO`