# Android Stream Audio to Java Server

Tags: android, audio

I am developing an Android app, the user can speak and the app will send the voice to the computer java server. I have used the following codes but it seems that it does not work. I use my IPV4 address and codes from here 
[Stream Live Android Audio to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server)

The errors are when I run this app, it tells me it has stopped working, however there are other errors, could anyone help me to get it fixed? Thank you.

1) I create a android project and put the codes in the MainActivity.
2) I create a java project and place it in a class.
3) I run the server.
4) I plug in my android device and run it on the device.
5) When I press start (to start recording), it doesn't work.

My Android App:

```
    package com.example.mictest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button startButton,stopButton;

public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private int port=50005;
AudioRecord recorder;

private int sampleRate = 44100;
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
private boolean status = true;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);

    startButton.setOnClickListener (startListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener (stopListener);

    minBufSize += 2048;
    System.out.println("minBufSize: " + minBufSize);
}

private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS","Recorder released");
    }

};

private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
                startStreaming();           
    }

};

public void startStreaming() {


    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                    Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                    DatagramPacket packet;

                    final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("172.20.129.255");
                    Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*10);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                recorder.startRecording();


                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                    socket.send(packet);
                    Log.d("VS", "MinBufferSize: " +minBufSize);


                }


            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
            } 
        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
 }
 }
```

My Java Server:

```
    package com.datagram;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 44100;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);

    /**
     * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
     * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
     * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
     * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
     */

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[4000];

    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

    while (status == true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);

        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());

        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
        toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());

    }
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl)           sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(100.0f);

        sourceDataLine.start();
        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        sourceDataLine.start();

        System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Amazing... It helped me a lot. Your code does almost half of that what I want to do. But I need your help, if you have time. Please

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your code in the while-loop

```
while(status == true) {
                //YOU WANT TO RECORD IN YOUR BUFFERSIZE?
                //reading data from MIC into buffer
                minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                //putting buffer in the packet
                packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                socket.send(packet);
                Log.d("VS", "MinBufferSize: " +minBufSize);
            }
```