# Streaming audio from Android app to PHP server

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

I want to stream audio from my Android app to PHP server.

I found one solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server), but I want to do this not in Java, rather in PHP + HTML5 + JS.
How can I do that? Is there any JS plugins to handle audio streaming?

Comment: You want a Java-code Android application to stream audio to a PHP server using PHP/HTML/JS (again, inside an Android application)?

Comment: I want to stream audio from android app to web-browser. One person is speaking to the smartphone, second person is listening on browser - and they can't send stream from browser to android, it's one way only.

Comment: Why not use the working Java code? What have you tried regarding PHP/HTML/JS?

Comment: My client don't want to run Java in browser to handle streaming, that is why I'm looking for other possibilities.