# Android streaming microphone

Tags: android

I want to live stream Android microphone which can be heard using a VLC player etc.

Playstore have mainly IP Camera apps but these are over the internal network. I want to stream over the internet.

Is it possible?

I tried the following code snippet but it is not working at the moment:

```
public void audiostream()

    {

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
        try {

            mp.setDataSource(getBaseContext(),Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.3"));
            mp.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        mp.start(); 

    }
```

Over at the VLC player, I tried listening (Media -> Stream -> set 192.168.1.3 as IP) but couldn't get anything.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

[MediaPlayer.setDataSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29) sets where the MediaPlayer will stream *from*, right now MediaPlayer is trying to play from that IP Address.

You need to implement some sort of Audio streaming server on top of android, something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server) if i understand your question correctly.

Do have in mind that question seems to be using a custom protocol, hence the custom java program he mentions. You would need to research on audio streaming protocols to implement a known standard that works with VLC.