# Record calls using stream in android

Tags: android

How to write the recorded call from android application to java server using streams in android sources. 
Any one can help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start maybe with "MediaPlayer" or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server

Comment: Ok, am using media player only but how can i pass the data(in the sense which type) from the mobile to server.

Comment: Have you tried to use this powerful search engine google?

Comment: And one more thing #Mertuarez, without storing the recorded voice has a file in mobile.directly storing in server. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should just make a stream(casual TCP) and broadcast that file as it is. I see no reason to use some specific audio stream from your description.

Comment: Oh!!.. okay thanks #Mertuarez

Comment: Okay guys, Thank you so much for ur references !!.. finally i got an answer based on replies given by #Mertuarez.