# Android I want to stream audio

Tags: android, audio

I'am writing an audio streming code but I cant bring more .

I want to use AudioTrack .

track.write(baiss);

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1280];
                int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,N*10,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                track.play();

                while(true)
                {
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData());

                    ... THIS CODE


                    Log.e("LOG","DATA ALINIYOR...");
                    Log.e("LOG","DATA : " + baiss.toString());

                }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15694209/5599807

Comment: AudioInputStream not working android

Comment: add `track.write(receivePacket .getData(), 0, receivePacket .getLength()); ` incide `while`

Comment: It is worked . Thank you . It has same noise . Thank you